# Axis border missing once using Matlab2tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

when I use Matlab2tikz to generate tikz file for my Matlab figure, it happens **sometimes** that some axis borders will disappear in the resulting PDF after compilation as shown in the following figure:

[image]
the problem appears only from time to time, and I still can't find an explanation. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you please show (some) of the code that matlab2tikz generates?

Comment: Does the line appear if you zoom in?